Woman has recurring dreams about trains
If I recall correctly, the woman is about to become 25 and she mentions that, ever since she was at the age of 5, she has had a dream where she has to pick the correct train from twenty of them and every single year she picks the wrong one. For every year that passes, and every wrong train she took, there is one less train for her to pick. I don't have anymore information about the movie, nor do I know the plot, because I didn't see past the first 15-45 minutes.
EDIT: 
Language: English
Country: USA or (possibly) Canada
Approximate Date: I saw this movie on TV in December 2006/January 2007 but I would venture to say that the movie wasn't made before 2000

Language\country? Approximate decade?

This appears to be Code 46 with Tim Robbins from 2003. You were close, it's 20 stations, not trains. Here's the dream of the young heroine played by Samantha Morton (from the dialogue):

Every year on my birthday I have a dream. Always the same dream. I go down into the subway, I wait for the train.
The train leaves the station. I feel like going to sleep, but there's someone I have to find. And I have to find him before the train stops. The train goes through one station. There are 19 more to go. I have to find him. And then I wake up.
The next year I had exactly the same dream. Only this time I went past two stations. Don't ask me how I knew. I just knew that there were 18 stations to go. Next year, 17. Next year, 16. Every birthday, one less.
Today's my birthday. Today I'm down to the last one. If I fall asleep, I'll get to my destination. If I want to, I can discover my fate tonight.

She meets the hero on that last birthday. Here's the trailer:




Thank you for the information. It's quite serendipitous to find out ,after all this time, that the people who made Hackers and Wargames also had their hand in making a movie like this. And now I get to enjoy another film of theirs. Once again, I thank you.

...Wait, how is Code 46 connected to Hackers & Wargames? You lost me. :) Or do you mean MGM\UA?

Yes. I was referring to the fact that it was made by UA
